# About dense sets used in the definition of forcing equality?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In Kunen's Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs, Ch. VII, section 3, page 195, in definition 3.3 about forcing equality, it reads:

$p \Vdash^* t_1 = t_2  \text { iff }  \\ \space \space (\alpha) \ \text {forall } \langle \pi_1,s_1 \rangle \in t_1,\\ \space\\ \space \space \{q \leq p : q \leq s_1 \to \exists \langle \pi_2,s_2 \rangle \in t_2 \,(q \leq s_2 \land q \Vdash^* \pi_1=\pi_2)\} \\ \space \\ \text {is dense below } p, \text { and } \\ \space \space (\beta) \ \text{forall } \langle \pi_2,s_2 \rangle \in t_2,\\ \space \\ \space \space  \{q \leq p : q \leq s_2 \to \exists \langle \pi_1,s_1 \rangle \in t_1 \, (q \leq s_1 \land q \Vdash^* \pi_1=\pi_2)\} \\ \space \\\text { is dense below } p$.

My question is that this definition includes conditions $q \leq p \land q \not \leq s_1$ , and  $q \leq p \land q \not \leq s_2$ in the definition of the first and second sets respectively?

What's the reason for including those conditions? Why not just using sets:

$\{q \leq p : q \leq s_1 \land \exists \langle \pi_2,s_2 \rangle \in t_2 \, (q \leq s_2 \land q \Vdash^* \pi_1=\pi_2)\} \\ \{q \leq p : q \leq s_2 \land \exists \langle \pi_1,s_1 \rangle \in t_1 \, (q \leq s_1 \land q \Vdash^* \pi_1=\pi_2)\}$

in the above definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline answer for those fairly new to Forcing (with P-names having a dot over them):

Taking as the example :

$p \Vdash^* \dot t_1 = \dot t_2  \text { iff }  \\ \space \space (\alpha) \ \text {forall } \langle \dot \pi_1,s_1 \rangle \in \dot t_1,\\ \space\\ \space \space \{q \leq p : q \leq s_1 \to \exists \langle \dot \pi_2,s_2 \rangle \in \dot t_2 \,(q \leq s_2 \land q \Vdash^* \dot \pi_1=\dot \pi_2)\} \\ \space \\ \text {is dense below } p$

Lets assume for simplicity, in $\Bbb P$, below the element p there are just two disjoint branches, one containing $s_1$ and one not containing $s_1$. One key point to note is that $q \nleq s_1$ has two possible solutions in a partial order : [$q > s_1$] OR [$ q \ngtr s_1$ AND $ q \nleq s_1$]. So $q \nleq s_1$ could include all $q < p$ in the branch not containing $s_1$.

The intended interpretation of $p \Vdash^*$ is that all G which contain p will satisfy $(\alpha)$ in the model M[G] containing G. However within the base model M not even one G is known. So $(\alpha)$ must work with all G containing p and all possible $\Bbb P$ in M. (We will for ease restrict $\Bbb P$ to the example mentioned above)

There are two cases :

**Case 1 : $\langle \dot \pi_1,s_1 \rangle$ is not activated**

Some (or all) of these G do not contain $s_1$, so may have elements in the path below p not containing $s_1$, or above $s_1$ but less than p. In this case it doesn't matter since $\langle \dot \pi_1,s_1 \rangle$ will not be activated when determining the expressions true in M[G] and will take no part in determining equality of $\dot t_1$[G] and $\dot t_2$[G] in M[G]. So these particular $q \nleq s_1$ are valid inputs to $(\alpha)$.

**Case 2 : $\langle \dot \pi_1,s_1 \rangle$ is activated**

Some (or all) of these G do contain $s_1$ and in this case $(\alpha)$ applies with the cases $q  \leq s_1 $.

**Always achieving dense below p when required**

Since $(\alpha)$ has to work with both those G not containing $s_1$, and with those G containing $s_1$, then both cases $q \nleq s_1$ and $q\leq s_1$ need to be included in the dense set definition. If only the $q\leq s_1$ cases were included then the set in $(\alpha)$ may not be dense below p, since there would be no elements from the path below p not containing $s_1$ (in the $\Bbb P$ assumed in this answer).

Answer (score 2):

Because what you want to posit is that the two sets are dense. Just because $\langle\pi_1,s_1\rangle\in t_1$ does not mean that $p$ itself already forces that $s_1$ is in $t_1$, or that any name that might be equal to it is forced by $p$ to be in $t_1$.

When we phrase it in way of implication we also allow all those conditions which *do not* force $s_1$ to be in $t_1$, or even force that it is not in $t_1$ at all, to be included in the set, thus ensuring that it will be dense, since "eventually an answer must be given" as to whether or not $s_1$ is in or out.

Comment: why we cannot work with the sets I've proposed? I admit that I'm confused about this issue. my point is that $p$ is in some $G$ right, so definitely the part of $\sf P$ below $s$ is already dense. So I don't see why should we include those condition which can force otherwise or even not force anything, they seem to me to be irrelevant for the purpose of defining equality. What seems (to me) to be needed is that the conditions below $s$ that fulfill the forcing formula to be dense, but those above it does'nt seem to be relevant. For example what happens if we adopt the two sets I've proposed?

Comment: You don't have access to $G$, and you want to define this *internally to the ground model*. Moreover, as I said, what if some $q_0\leq p$ forces that $t_1$ is empty, and another $q_1\leq p$ forces that $t_1$ is not empty?

Comment: But the same thing still occur with the original definition, I mean the definition is including all $q \leq p \land q \not \leq s$ without requiring those to meet any forcing condition.